# Split strings with multiple delimiters R

Tags: r, split

Similar questions were asked before here but the symbols are quite confusing to me. Here is an example dataset I have.

```
id <- c(1,2)
form <-  c("AA-BB-c2C-Dat-D-SP18-CC", "AA::B2S::DD::C::SP17::GG")

data <- data.frame(id, form)
> data
  id                     form
1  1  AA-BB-c2C-Dat-D-SP18-CC
2  2 AA::B2S::DD::C::SP17::GG
```

The first row has 7 objects separated by "-", the second row has 6 objects separated by "::". I would like to grab the second last object's (SP18 and SP19) numeric values as below.

```
> data
  id                     form  sub.form  
1  1  AA-BB-c2C-Dat-D-SP18-CC   18
2  2 AA::B2S::DD::C::SP17::GG   17
```

Any thoughts and some helpful material do you have in your mind for me to read through about this string documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here for a base R option:

```
data$sub.form <- sub("^.*\\bSP(\\d+)\\b.*$", "\\1", data$form)
data

  id                     form sub.form
1  1  AA-BB-c2C-Dat-D-SP18-CC       18
2  2 AA::B2S::DD::C::SP17::GG       17
```